# How to find WHICH user account changed Order Status in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, order-status

I have a Magento2 store with multiple logistics staff members working on the same Orders list and Verifying, Cancelling, or Processing orders by changing their status

I want to find *which* user account performed the order status change, e.g. in the screenshot below; add the username or email address of the account which changed status

Is something like that possible? I tried to google a lot but no relevant results for my query.

[image: order status change]

Comment: Magento  does not have default feature to log admin activity

Answer (score 0):

If you have Magento 2 Community version it will not be possible out of the box and you will need to look at 3rd party extensions.

If you are on Adobe Commerce (Enterprise Edition), you can follow the below steps.

This information is in the Action Logs Report. You can access it as shown below:

[image]

You can then search for action group "sales orders" to filter down to order level changes. You can also use the details column to filter particular orders by order number.